# i can't create a static method in Nop.Services.Customers.CustomerService

Tags: c#, oop, nopcommerce

I try to create a static function in **Nop.Services.Customers.CustomerService** for get

customer list in the nop database. I want to call this function in an external Console

Application. But **CustomerService**  class not contains the default constructor.

Please see the constructor code.

```
  #region Ctor

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheManager">Cache manager</param>
    /// <param name="customerRepository">Customer repository</param>
    /// <param name="customerRoleRepository">Customer role repository</param>
    /// <param name="customerAttributeRepository">Customer attribute repository</param>
    /// <param name="encryptionService">Encryption service</param>
    /// <param name="newsLetterSubscriptionService">Newsletter subscription service</param>
    /// <param name="rewardPointsSettings">Reward points settings</param>
    /// <param name="customerSettings">Customer settings</param>
    /// <param name="eventPublisher"></param>
    public CustomerService(ICacheManager cacheManager,
        IRepository<Customer> customerRepository,
        IRepository<CustomerRole> customerRoleRepository,
        IRepository<CustomerAttribute> customerAttributeRepository,
        IEncryptionService encryptionService, INewsLetterSubscriptionService newsLetterSubscriptionService,
        RewardPointsSettings rewardPointsSettings, CustomerSettings customerSettings,
        IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
    {
        _cacheManager = cacheManager;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _customerRoleRepository = customerRoleRepository;
        _customerAttributeRepository = customerAttributeRepository;
        _encryptionService = encryptionService;
        _newsLetterSubscriptionService = newsLetterSubscriptionService;
        _rewardPointsSettings = rewardPointsSettings;
        _customerSettings = customerSettings;
        _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    #endregion
```

And Fileds is shows the error when try to call in the static function.

Please see the fields

```
  #region Fields

    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<CustomerRole> _customerRoleRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<CustomerAttribute> _customerAttributeRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<FileUpload> _fileuploadRepository;
    private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;
    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
    private readonly INewsLetterSubscriptionService _newsLetterSubscriptionService;
    private readonly RewardPointsSettings _rewardPointsSettings;
    private readonly CustomerSettings _customerSettings;
    private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;

    #endregion
```

I create a default in CustomerService class.

```
 public CustomerService()
 {
 }
```

and create new function in CustomerService

```
 public virtual List<Customer> GetClients()
    {
        var _cust = _customerRepository.Table;

        return _cust.ToList();
    }
```

and call this function in an external console application

```
    private static CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Customer> cust = _customerService.GetClients();

        ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(ProcessMails);
        thread = new Thread(start);
        ProcessStatus = 1;
        thread.Start();
    }
```

But when i call this function it's shows the null error.

[image]

It's not possible to create a function in Nop.Core and call in an external application?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From class definition, it is not possible. Static methods are for the type, not for the instance, so the member variable can be used in a static method should be static too.